# Android Keypad All caps not working on Samsung S4 devices

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am facing this issue with Samsung S4 devices only. Here is my code,

```
edtPasscode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPasscode);
edtPasscode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS
        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS
        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES
        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

The above code works on all other models, but doesn't work on S4 devices alone. I verified it on two Samsung S4 devices running 4.4.4 and 5.0.1. Both has the same issue. Any help is appreciated.

Here is a screenshot,

[image: keypad issue]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.AllCaps.html

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the described behavior my S4. I would guess that you're using a keyboard that doesn't respect those flags.

Comment: @MikeM. Its just the default keypad. But then, I verified on two devices.. Not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: @Sree I tried your suggestion. It changes the text in the edittext to caps. But I need the keypad to display the characters in uppercase. It still shows  lower case.

Comment: can i see what changes you have made

Comment: Every developer knows (or should know) that Samsung software is inherently broken. They don't follow convention, break in places no other devices does, etc. We even have a `Samsung` label to put on our github issues. Said all that, those flags is a request, and it's obviously that keyboard is not following the request. So your best option is to file a bug report on samsung website and just use the filter to force the `InputFilter` to force the data to be correct.

Comment: @Sree - Added the below code edtPasscode.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});

Comment: if you want text data in caps, just convert text data to toUpperCase()  when you use, and do you tried android:capitalize="characters" in your xml?

Comment: I understand. I tried, android:capitalize="characters as well. But, this is a passcode edittext and the user will be provided with passcode that is fully caps. It might confuse the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a long struggle, I just found that, it has nothing to do with the code. It's actually the keypad settings that needs to be changed. 
From **Settings->Language and Input->Enable Auto Capitalize option**

This seems to be a odd behavior on samsung S4 in my opinion.